# Align section content

Tags: xetex, titlesec

I have section headings starting with an icon, I'd like section content to be aligned with the first character in the title, not with the icon. I managed to do it hardcoding the distance with \hspace, is there another way to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\colorlet{RED}{red}

\titleformat{\section}{
    \scshape
    \raggedright\uppercase}{}{0em}{\textcolor{red}{\faTwitter \thinspace}
}



\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\colorlet{RED}{red}

\titleformat{\section}{
    \scshape
    \raggedright\uppercase}{}{0em}{\llap{\color{red}\faTwitter \thinspace}}

\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @bernard, it does exactly what I need.